# In Where clause add check if Parameter is empty string

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements, sql-server-2014

I must write query in SQL which will return Account Id.

For this query i have input parameters, which can be empty.

In database here is rows where some field is null or empty. So in case parameter is empty i also need to check field if it's null.

```
SELECT a.Account_ID   
    FROM Accounts a
    WHERE a.FirstName = @FirstName /*Add check if @FirstName = '' then a.FirstName IS NULL */ 
        AND a.LastName = @LastName 
        AND a.Middle = @MiddleName
        AND a.Email = @Email 
        AND a.Company = @Company
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a or condition you need:

```
SELECT a.Account_ID   
    FROM Accounts a
    WHERE ((@FirstName='' and a.FirstName is null) or a.FirstName = @FirstName) /*Add check if @FirstName = '' then a.FirstName IS NULL */ 
        AND a.LastName = @LastName 
        AND a.Middle = @MiddleName
        AND a.Email = @Email 
        AND a.Company = @Company
```

Comment: I like your answer. Even if it's almost the same with @gordatron answer, i think check `(@firstname != '' AND a.FirstName = @FirstName) ` is necessary

Comment: @demo I don't think so. if `@firstname !=''` first part of the query returns false and second part is executet. if `(@firstname =''` only the first part will be executed.

Comment: so @gordatron answer cover all cases?

Comment: In my opinion both querys should give you the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I normally do something like this if i want special behavior for empty params:

```
SELECT a.Account_ID   
FROM Accounts a
WHERE 
 (
     (@firstname != '' AND a.FirstName = @FirstName) 
     OR (@firstname = '' AND a.FirstName is null)
 )
 AND a.LastName = @LastName AND a.Middle = @MiddleName
 AND a.Email = @Email AND a.Company = @Company
```

I have a bracketed OR that handles the case for param = '' and param != '' specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question but does this help?

```
SELECT a.Account_ID   
FROM Accounts a
WHERE ISNULL(a.FirstName,'') = @FirstName 
    AND a.LastName = @LastName 
    AND a.Middle = @MiddleName
    AND a.Email = @Email 
    AND a.Company = @Company
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.Account_ID   
FROM Accounts a
WHERE 1 = (CASE WHEN @FirstName != '' AND a.FirstName = @FirstName THEN 1 
                WHEN @FirstName = '' AND a.FirstName IS NULL THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
           END) AND 
      a.LastName = @LastName AND 
      a.Middle = @MiddleName AND 
      a.Email = @Email AND 
      a.Company = @Company
```

Answer (score 0):

A case-clause can just as well be used in a where condition as in the list of selected fields:

```
SELECT a.Account_ID   
    FROM Accounts a
    WHERE case when @FirstName = '' then a.FirstName = @FirstName 
               else a.FirstName IS NULL 
          end
      AND a.LastName = @LastName 
      AND a.Middle = @MiddleName
      AND a.Email = @Email 
      AND a.Company = @Company
```